# C# riddle; test from potential employer with DateTime as method parameter, and empty constructor

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting, type-conversion

A potential employer sent me the following code and simply said that it contained some problems and needed to be rewritten to work properly. There was no context given.

```
1.  class DateEx
2.   static INT hasFormatted == false
3.   public dateEx(){}
4.   public string formatDate( DateTime myDate=null ) {
5.       if hasFormatted = true
6.         return "The date "myDate" is already formatted.";
7.       else
8.          return string.format("{0:m/d/yyyy}"  myDate);
9.       }
10.      return myDate;
11.   }
```

I identified this as C#, but cannot figure out the meaning or context of what is intended here. Here is where I am now; stuck.

```
using System;

class DateEx 
{
    static bool hasFormatted = false;

    //empty constructor not required
    //public DateEx(){}

    //make the struct nullable
    public string formatDate(DateTime? myDate = null) 
    {
        //replace the null
        if (!myDate.HasValue)
        {
        myDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        //if (myDate == null) 
        //  myDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Year, DateTime.Month, DateTime.Day);

        if (hasFormatted == true) 
        {
            return "The date " + myDate + " is already formatted.";
        }
        else 
        {
            return String.Format("0:m/d/yyyy",  myDate);
        }
    return myDate;
    }
}
```

I realize this has something to do with a class that will chop off the time part of DateTime of it exists. It seems to me that it doesn't mean a lot unless in addition to correcting problems, new lines of code are added or maybe moved? I am on Hour 5 of trying to solve this as I make this post.

The remaining errors I get when running my above code through the C# compiler on www.ideone.com is:

```
Compilation error   time: 0 memory: 0 signal:0
prog.cs(30,12): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.DateTime?' to `string'
error CS5001: Program `prog.exe' does not contain a static `Main' method suitable for an entry point
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, the last `return myDate;` is superfluous. First it returns the wrong type (need to return `string` but it's returning `DateTime`), and secondly it's actually unreachable code (the `if/else` block has a `return` in both branches) Personally, without context, it's hard to say what else you're supposed to do. Maybe you can mention that `hasFormatted` is never assigned a value, or assume it should be set to `true` in the `else` branch. The second error your have (about the lack of a `Main` method) can probably be ignored: they didn't send you a console application, they sent you a class.

Comment: I think you tried this code in a Console application if yes please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the number of syntax errors and convention violations in the short example, I think the intention is to see how much you know about the syntax of the language and its naming conventions.

Going line by line, here is what you have:

1. Missing curly brace
2. Wrong data type, non-conventional name, wrong assignment operator, and a missing semicolon
3. This line is illegal in its entirety (do you know why?)
4. Non-conventional name of the method, and an invalid attempt at using a default argument (do you know why?)
5. Completely wrong syntax of the `if` statement, and a wrong equality comparison operator `==`
6. Incorrect way of using double-quotes in a string literal
7. Missing opening curly brace for an unbalanced brace on line 9
8. Missing separator between parameters of `string.Format`, and a wrong capitalization of the method's name
9. OK
10. Trying to return an object of a wrong type
11. OK
12. (this line is missing) Need a closing curly brace for the class

Answer (score -1):

I hope you tried this with a Console application,if yes your class should have the below method.this is because the main() method is the entry point.

```
 public void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
```

and you should write your codes inside this method.
Please see the below code

```
public class Program
{
    static bool hasFormatted = false;
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        formatDate();
    }
    public string formatDate(DateTime? myDate = null)
    {

        string formateddDate;
        //replace the null
        if (!myDate.HasValue)
        {
            myDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        //if (myDate == null) 
        //  myDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Year, DateTime.Month, DateTime.Day);

        if (hasFormatted == true)
        {
            return "The date " + myDate + " is already formatted.";
        }
        else
        {
             formateddDate= String.Format("{0:m/dd/yyyy}", myDate);
        }
        return formateddDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: But the task said nothing about console application. I guess, he needs to fix the given class.

Comment: But From the error we could know that he tried this in a Console App

Comment: Thank you, this also helped.